# How to get data using select from a nested properties - linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity

Here is my data structure:

```
public class Product
{
    // Rest of props

    public ICollection<ProductUpdate> ProductUpdate { get; set; }
}

public class ProductUpdate 
{
    // Rest of props

    public Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
}

public class Delivery
{
    // Rest of props

    public virtual ICollection<DeliveryUsersApprovers> DeliveryUsersApprovers { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryUsersApprovers
{
    // Rest of props

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

How can I write a linq method syntax query that would select `Id`, `StartDate` and `Note` from `ProductUpdate`, while it would select for each row `ProductUpdate` cooresponding User which made update which is contained in `DeliveryUsersApprovers` class..
I would like to achieve it using `.Select()` to get only needed columns..

I've tried something like this but that is not working :

```
var paymentStatusUpdates = await _dbContext.Product.Include(x => x.ProductUpdate)
.Select(x => new SomeCustomClassObjectWithFourProperties
{
    // Read data from ProductUpdate somehow and select Id, Date and Note from ProductUpdate and  get User from nested property
                           .Select(y=> new SomeCustomClassObjectWithFourProperties 
                           { 
                               Id = y.Id,
                               Date=y.StartDate,
                               Note=y.Note,
                               User=? // this is User from very nested prop
                           })

})
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == productId, cancellationToken); //productId is received in method params
```

I'm really struggling to get deep into nested prop and reach `User` for each `ProductUpdate` so any kind of help would be great !!

Thanks

Comment: You might use `SelectMany` for nested collections, but I'm not sure how this query can be translated into sql

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I dont know how, I'm really beginner here

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, wouldn't `Deliveries` property be a collection ?

Comment: @NamLe Its not collection, I renamed it to Delivery

Comment: So since 1 `ProductUpdate` may have 1 `Delivery`, 1 `Delivery` may have many `DeliveryUsersApprovers`, 1 `DeliveryUsersApprovers` may have 1 `User`, I conclude that 1 `ProductUpdate` may have many `User`, is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten `DeliveryUsersApprovers` collection, then map every `DeliveryUsersApprovers` into a `Result` object that contain its `User` and `ProductUpdate`'s data.

I tried this out on a dummy `IEnumerable`, please replace `products` in my example with your `_dbContext.Product.Include(x => x.ProductUpdate)` to see if it works.

```
var products = new List<Product>();

var results = products.Select(product => product.ProductUpdate
                .SelectMany(productUpdate => productUpdate.Delivery.DeliveryUsersApprovers
                    .Select(deliveryUsersApprovers => new Result()
                        {
                            Id = productUpdate.Id,
                            Date = productUpdate.Date,
                            Note = productUpdate.Note,
                            User = deliveryUsersApprovers.User
                        })));
```